# This pack is missing one or more dependencies - JSON behavior pack code is not working. -Minecraft bedrock

Tags: json, minecraft

I have been trying to get this Minecraft bedrock behavior pack working for a while now. I used a [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/behaviorpack), so I could learn how to make behavior packs but no matter how many times I look back through it, I still can't figure out what the problem is. The referenced texture pack works fine, but the behavior does not work.

- Minecraft bedrock v1.17.34.

in file : development_resource_packs > RP cow

This is the `manifest.json` for the resource pack.

```
// development_resource_packs > RP cow > manifest.json

{
      "format_version": 2,
      "header": {
        "description": "My First Add-On!",
        "name": "Hello WorldRP",
        "uuid":"9b0e1712-ba26-4d3c-be42-2b6c4d160305",
        "version": [1, 0, 0],
        "min_engine_version": [1, 16, 0]
      },
      "modules": [
        {
          "description": "My First Add-On!",
          "type": "resources",
          "uuid": "f2ccdadd-c9ac-4d53-8daf-a3520537ea7e",
          "version": [1, 0, 0]
        }
      ]
    }
```

```
// development_behavior_packs > HelloWorldBP > manifest.json

{
  "format_version": 2,
  "header": {
    "description": "My First Add-On!",
    "name": "Hello WorldBP",
    "uuid":"c3fac618-a713-4516-b1eb-1b9c7c75b1db",
    "version": [1, 0, 0],
    "min_engine_version": [1, 16, 0]
  },
  "modules":
    [
      {
        "description": "My First Add-On!",
          "type": "data",
          "uuid": "e34d68ac-72f2-44c2-a514-b83673f919c0",
          "version": [1, 0, 0]
      }
    ],
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "uuid":"9b0e1712-ba26-4d3c-be42-2b6c4d160305",
      "version":[1,0,0]
    }
 ]
}
```

```
// HelloWorldBP > entities > cow.json

{
  "format_version": "1.16.0",
  "minecraft:entity": {
    "description": {
      "identifier": "minecraft:cow",
      "is_spawnable": true,
      "is_summonable": true,
      "is_experimental": false
    },
    "component_groups": {
      "minecraft:cow_baby": {
        "minecraft:is_baby": {
        },
        "minecraft:scale": {
          "value":0.5
        },
        "minecraft:ageable": {
          "duration": 1200,
          "feed_items": "wheat",
          "grow_up": {
            "event": "minecraft:ageable_grow_up",
            "target": "self"
          }
        },

        "minecraft:behavior.follow_parent": {
          "priority": 6,
          "speed_multiplier": 1.1
        }
      },

      "minecraft:cow_adult": {
        "minecraft:experience_reward": {
          "on_bred": "Math.Random(1,7)",
          "on_death": "query.last_hit_by_player ? Math.Random(1,3) : 0"
        },
        "minecraft:loot": {
          "table": "loot_tables/entities/cow.json"
        },
        "minecraft:behavior.breed": {
          "priority": 3,
          "speed_multiplier": 1.0
        },
        "minecraft:breedable": {
          "require_tame": false,
          "breed_items": "wheat",
          "breeds_with": {
            "mate_type": "minecraft:cow",
            "baby_type": "minecraft:cow",
            "breed_event": {
              "event": "minecraft:entity_born",
              "target": "baby"
            }
          }
        },
        "minecraft:interact": {
          "interactions": [
            {
              "on_interact": {
                "filters": {
                  "all_of": [
                    { "test": "is_family", "subject" : "other", "value" :  "player"},
                    { "test": "has_equipment", "domain": "hand", "subject": "other", "value": "bucket:0"}
                  ]
                }
              },
              "use_item": true,
              "transform_to_item": "bucket:1",
              "play_sounds": "milk",
              "interact_text": "action.interact.milk"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    "components": {
  "minecraft:type_family": {
    "family": [ "cow", "mob" ]
  },
  "minecraft:breathable": {
    "total_supply": 15,
    "suffocate_time": 0
  },
  "minecraft:navigation.walk": {
    "can_path_over_water": true,
    "avoid_water": true,
    "avoid_damage_blocks": true
  },
  "minecraft:movement.basic": {
  },
  "minecraft:jump.static": {
  },
  "minecraft:can_climb": {
  },
  "minecraft:collision_box": {
    "width": 0.9,
    "height": 1.3
  },
  "minecraft:nameable": {
  },
  "minecraft:health": {
    "value": 10,
    "max": 10
  },
  "minecraft:hurt_on_condition": {
    "damage_conditions": [
      {
        "filters": { "test": "in_lava", "subject": "self", "operator": "==", "value": true },
        "cause": "lava",
        "damage_per_tick": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  "minecraft:movement": {
    "value": 0.25
  },
  "minecraft:despawn": {
    "despawn_from_distance": {}
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.float": {
    "priority": 0
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.panic": {
    "priority": 1,
    "speed_multiplier": 1.25
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.mount_pathing": {
    "priority": 2,
    "speed_multiplier": 1.5,
    "target_dist": 0.0,
    "track_target": true
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.breed": {
    "priority": 3,
    "speed_multiplier": 1.0
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.tempt": {
    "priority": 4,
    "speed_multiplier": 1.25,
    "items": [
      "wheat"
    ]
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.follow_parent": {
    "priority": 5,
    "speed_multiplier": 1.1
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.random_stroll": {
    "priority": 6,
    "speed_multiplier": 0.8
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.look_at_player": {
    "priority": 7,
    "look_distance": 6.0,
    "probability": 0.02
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.random_look_around": {
    "priority": 9
  },
  "minecraft:leashable": {
    "soft_distance": 4.0,
    "hard_distance": 6.0,
    "max_distance": 10.0
  },
  "minecraft:balloonable": {
  },
  "minecraft:rideable": {
    "seat_count": 1,
    "family_types": [
      "zombie"
    ],
    "seats": {
      "position": [ 0.0, 1.105, 0.0 ]
    }
  },
  "minecraft:physics": {
  },
  "minecraft:pushable": {
    "is_pushable": true,
    "is_pushable_by_piston": true
  },
  "minecraft:conditional_bandwidth_optimization": {
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.nearest_attackable_target":{
    "priority": 2,
    "must_see":true,
    "reselect_targets": true,
    "within_radius": 25.0,
    "entity_types":[
      {
        "filters":{
          "test": "is_family", "subject": "other", "value": "player"
        },
        "max_dist":32
      }
    ]
  },
  "minecraft:behavior.melee_attack": {
    "priority": 3
  },
  "minecraft:attack":{
    "damage": 3
  }
},
    "events": {
      "minecraft:entity_spawned": {
        "randomize": [
          {
            "weight": 95,
            "trigger": "minecraft:spawn_adult"
          },
          {
            "weight": 5,
            "add": {
              "component_groups": [
                "minecraft:cow_baby"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },

      "minecraft:entity_born": {
        "add": {
          "component_groups": [
            "minecraft:cow_baby"
          ]
        }
      },

      "minecraft:entity_transformed": {
        "remove": {
        },
        "add": {
          "component_groups": [
            "minecraft:cow_adult"
          ]
        }
      },

      "minecraft:ageable_grow_up": {
        "remove": {
          "component_groups": [
            "minecraft:cow_baby"
          ]
        },
        "add": {
          "component_groups": [
            "minecraft:cow_adult"
          ]
        }
      },

      "minecraft:spawn_adult": {
        "add": {
          "component_groups": [
            "minecraft:cow_adult"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enable experimental featurs. to think after a day I would not realize that was all I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

```
This pack is missing one or more dependencies. Would you like to apply it anyway?
```

I was also following Microsoft's [Introduction to Behavior Packs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/behaviorpack) tutorial. This was the error the game provided when I tried to load my behavior pack into a new world. Sure enough, my cows did not attack me :-(

### Solution #1:

I needed to do 2 things to resolve this error.

#### 1. Correct the typo in the name of the `entities` folder.

As the [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/behaviorpack#troubleshooting) section suggests, check the spelling of this and other folders!

#### 2. Remove the entry in `invalid_known_packs` for my behavior pack.

```
// com.Mojang > minecraftpe > invalid_known_packs.json
// This was part of the file.

{
        "file_system" : "RawPath",
        "from_disk" : true,
        "hashes" : [ "gc9MQR+ZUuk6kivtMInudDFbammayhdk5vdSMVUzFP4=" ],
        "path" : "C:/Users/<my user>/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe/LocalState/games/com.mojang/development_behavior_packs/MadCows",
        "uuid" : "<my uuid>",
        "version" : "1.0.0"
},
```

It appears that Minecraft will remember previously bad behavior packs, and it will not attempt to load them again! Once I removed the above entry, the cows attacked me as expected. :-)

### Solution #2:

Sometimes this error is an error, and when I play the game anyway, my mod works as expected.